# Skip list on java extending AbstractMap

Tags: java, data-structures, java-collections-api

I need to implement skip list in java. I know how skip list works, but i need to extend AbstractMap. So class SkipList would look like

```
public class SkipList<K extends Comparable<K>,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> {
public SkipList(int levels) {
    // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

I don't understand how i need to extend AbstractMap

Answer (score 0):

**SkipList** is used for fast search, usually with `O(logn)` time complexity. Standard JDK has no implementation of it. While [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) is implemented using **SkipList** data structure, you can refer its source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.java#ConcurrentSkipListMap

Here is another good example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71432/custom-skiplist-implementation-in-java